# javascript pow parameters - Armstrong Numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, pow

Attempting to write the armstrong function.  I used chrome to debug and found that it bombs on val1 when I attempt to assign the result of pow .  I tried with both array[element] and array[element].value but its not liking either.

```js
//Armstrong numbers
function armstrong() {

var numberStr = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;
var numberInt = parseInt(numberStr);
var arrayOfNum = numberStr.split('');
var val1, val2, val3, total = 0;
   
var displayResult = document.getElementById('displayResult');

for (i = 0; i < arrayOfNum.length; i++) {
   arrayOfNum[i] = parseInt(arrayOfNum[i]);
}

if (arrayOfNum.length === 3) {
    val1 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[0], 3);
    val2 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[1], 3);
    val3 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[2], 3);
  
    total = val1 + val2 + val3;

    if (total === numberInt) {
        //display msg that number is armstrong
        displayResult.innerHTML = "Your number " + numberInt + " is an Armstrong Number.";
    } else {
        //display msg that not armstrong
        displayResult.innerHTML = "Your number " + numberInt + " is NOT an Armstrong Number.";
    }
} else {
    // display msg to enter a 3 digit number        
    displayResult.innerHTML = "You must enter a 3 digit number.";
}
}
```

Comment: Code above has been edited to show the solution.  I implemented Muhammad's suggestion and also parsed the initial value as an integer, it was storing it as a string even though the .value was used and the element was of type number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using pow .in javascript its Math.pow()
replace your code to this

```
val1 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[0].value, 3);
val2 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[1].value, 3);
val3 = Math.pow(arrayOfNum[2].value, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you! I removed .value from the arrays and also parseInt()'d the inputted value into a comparison variable.  The input element has a type of 'number' but it was still storing the initial input value as a string?  You'd think JS would store the right data type if its spelled out in the element?